# Checkbox not Rendering or Changing Checked value when state is changing

Tags: checkbox, state, react-native, react-native-ios

I have to change the value of Checkbox to Checked from Unchecked and vise-versa.

For that I am changing state on button click.

and if 'checked' state value is 'true' then Checkedbox should be checked. But, It not.

I have used property 'checked' and assigned state's boolean value.
So, it should render when state going to be changed but it not changing.

Is there any other way to render Checkbox ?

Comment: is your checkbox inside the listview or flatlist ?

Comment: No using single seperate Checkbox.

Comment: can you please show your code ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a code sample how to do that

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
   isChecked: false
  };
  render() {
    return (
     <View>
       <CheckBox
         value={this.state.isChecked}
         onValueChange={() =>
          this.setState({
           isChecked: !this.state.isChecked
         })
       }
       />
     </View>
   );
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using redux-form then, this is your solution :

```
<Field name="AcceptTAndC" component={(props) => {
      return (
              <View>
                  <ListItem>
                     <CheckBox {...props.input} checked={props.input.value ? true : false} onPress={() => {
                                    const val = !props.input.value;
                                    props.input.onChange(val);
                                    this.setState({ acceptTAndC: val });
                                }} />

                                <Text> I accept <Text onPress={() => this.refs.termsModal.open()}>this terms and conditions</Text></Text>
                            </ListItem>
                        </View>
                    )
 }} validate={[acceptTerms]}/> // "acceptTerms" is validation rules that imported from other file, but you may not need it for this
```

You can check details from here [code](https://github.com/arif2009/BloodConnector/blob/master/src/components/UserForm/UserCreateForm.js) and [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZgaLg.png)

Answer (score 0):

> as mentioned above by @Amila Dhulanjana, this function only changes the value of assigned state value, but it will not update the checkbox in HTML view until you assign the checked field.

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    isChecked: false,
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <CheckBox
          value={this.state.isChecked}
          checked={this.state.isChecked}
          onValueChange={() =>
            this.setState({
              isChecked: !this.state.isChecked,
            })
          }
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```